Authentication headers aren't working in Ktor client requests
When attempting to send requests to the persona API with the Ktor library I'm repeatedly met with:
Error

{"errors":[{"title":"Must be authenticated to access this endpoint"}]}

I have tried multiple solutions. The first is using the authentication as a header in Ktor:
        install(DefaultRequest){
                header("accept", "application/json")
                header("Persona-Version", "2023-01-05")
                header("authorization", "Bearer API_KEY")

          }

I have also tried this solution using differing headers:
      install(DefaultRequest){
              header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
              header("Persona-Version", "2023-01-05")
              header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer API_KEY")
       }

The second solution mentioned in the Persona API documentation has been to use the API key as a bearer token value which I have also tried.
       install(Auth){
         bearer{
                loadTokens{
                    BearerTokens(API_KEY, API_KEY)
                    }
                }
        }

I have also tried adding the headers directly to the get request to no avail. This solution has resulted in the same error message. I have tested the request both in python as well as using the Volley library and am able to easily retrieve the JSON response so the Persona API is definitely working.
Working code so far:
     import android.os.Bundle
     import android.util.Log
     import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
     import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     import io.ktor.client.*
     import io.ktor.client.call.*
     import io.ktor.client.engine.android.Android
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.DefaultRequest
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.RedirectResponseException
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.ServerResponseException
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.*
     import io.ktor.client.request.*
     import io.ktor.client.statement.*
     import io.ktor.http.*
     import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
     import io.ktor.server.application.*
     import kotlinx.coroutines.*
     import kotlinx.serialization.*
     import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.*
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.BearerTokens
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.bearer
     import io.ktor.client.plugins.defaultRequest
     import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonArray
     import org.json.JSONObject

     const val TAG = "MainActivity"


    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

        private val httpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {               
            json(Json{
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
            })

        install(Logging){logger = Logger.DEFAULT        
            level = LogLevel.ALL                                    
            }

        install(DefaultRequest){
            header("accept", "application/json")
            header("Persona-Version", "2023-01-05")
            header("authorization", "Bearer API KEY")

        }
           install(Auth){
            bearer{
                loadTokens{
                    BearerTokens(API KEY, API KEY)
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        coroutineScope.launch {

                 try {
                    val posts = httpClient.get { url("https://withpersona.com/api/v1/accounts")
                    }    
                    println(posts.bodyAsText())

                }   catch(e: RedirectResponseException){
                    // 3xx - responses
                    println("Error: ${e.response.status.description}")
                }   catch(e: ClientRequestException){
                    // 4xx - responses
                    println("Error: ${e.response.status.description}")
                }   catch(e: ServerResponseException){
                    //3xx - responses
                    println("Error: ${e.response.status.description}")
                }   catch(e: Exception){
                    println("Error: ${e.message}")
                }

                httpClient.close()
          }
       }
     }

I have tried multiple methods to add authentication headers to my get requests but keep getting the same error. This has not happened when using the volley library where I get the proper JSON response.

For me, the solution with the DefaultRequest plugin and the one where the Authorization header is added to the request, work. You don't seem to use any authentication mechanism in your last code snippet.

Edited the original post for clarity. This solution still doesn't seem to be working for me. Is there any additional syntax you added?

Please try using only one solution at a time. In the configuration of the DefaultRequest plugin, you can use the following code: header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer $apiKey"), where apiKey is a variable holding the Persona API key.

Unfortunately, no change whatsoever.

Solved! The API key was faulty. Needed to generate a new one.
